# create an array of objects grouped by date with count properties

Tags: javascript, arrays

So I have an array of objects that have the following schema:

```
{
    "isOpen" : false, 
    "updatedAt" : "2018-08-23T14:44:31.651+0000"
}
```

I need to convert them into an array of objects like so:

```
{
    date: "2018-08-23",
    added: 1,
    removed: 2
}
```

The way this is derived is by first grouping all objects together by date (`updatedAt` property). Then I would iterate over it to see which objects have a property `isOpen` set to `true` which means that they were added that day, or if its `false` they were removed on that day.

Kind of like this:

```
var data = {};
dataArray.forEach(function (item) {
    var key = item.updatedAt.split('T')[0];
    if(data.hasOwnProperty(key)){
        if(item.isOpen) data[key].added = data[key].added + 1;
        else data[key].removed = data[key].removed + 1;
    } else {
        if(item.isOpen) data[key] = {added: 1, removed: 0};
        else data[key] = {added: 0, removed: 1};
    }
});
var final = Object.keys(data).map(function (key) {
    return {
        date: key,
        added: data[key].added,
        removed: data[key].removed
    };
});
```

I hate to iterate over the arrays so many times. Is there a way to make this more efficient? Perhaps I can do the iterations in one loop somehow.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a good use of `reduce` which will cut down on the code a little. Then just add the date as you make the hash map. If you do that, your final array will be waiting in the result of  `Object.values()`:

```js
let dataArray = [{"isOpen" : false, "updatedAt" : "2018-08-23T14:44:31.651+0000"},{"isOpen" : true, "updatedAt" : "2018-08-23T14:44:31.651+0000"},{"isOpen" : true, "updatedAt" : "2018-08-23T14:44:31.651+0000"},{"isOpen" : false, "updatedAt" : "2018-07-23T14:44:31.651+0000"},{"isOpen" : false, "updatedAt" : "2018-07-23T14:44:31.651+0000"},{"isOpen" : true, "updatedAt" : "2018-07-23T14:44:31.651+0000"},{"isOpen" : true, "updatedAt" : "2018-08-23T14:44:31.651+0000"}]

let data = dataArray.reduce((data, item) => {
    let key = item.updatedAt.split('T')[0];
    let current = (data[key] || (data[key] = {date: key, added: 0, removed: 0}))
    current[item.isOpen ? 'added' : 'removed']  += 1
    return data
}, {});

console.log(Object.values(data))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can count your items in the loop like this. The object you lookup will have the key (date-prefix) and counts, so you don't have to map a second time.

```
var ret = {}
dataArray.forEach(function(item) {
  var date = item.updatedAt.split('T')[0];
  let counts = ret[date]
  if (!counts) {
    counts = {
      date,
      added: 0,
      removed: 0
    }
    ret[date] = counts
  }

  if (item.isOpen) counts.added++
    else counts.removed++;
})

var output = ret.values
```

Comment: I use that 'create if not in hash' approach all the time.  It is how all of the groupby implementations work.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the package jinqJS.

There's a **groupby** clause that it could be useful

https://jinqjs.readme.io/docs/groupby